# How to convert english date to arabic date in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am looking for method to transform English date in this format `dd/MMM/yyyy` to Arabic date

for example `18/Feb/2016` will be in Arabic  `١٨/فبراير/٢٠١٦`

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Questions asking us to find a tool, software library, or other off-site resource are off-topic

Comment: You can specify the culture when parsing (`DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)`) and formatting (`DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd dddd , MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"));
```

instead of the `DateTime.Now` just put whatever `DateTime` object you want to convert.

Comment: how to do it when I am formating date like this way TBDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(oraReder[2]).ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: It should be something like this: 
`TBDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(oraReder[2]).ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"));`

Comment: format did not changed no errors nothing changed TBNextDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(oraReder[4]).ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"));

Comment: It shows only month in Arabic while date and year values are shown in english digits.

Comment: Even I thought it would solve the problem for me but only shows the month in Arabic and not the date and year. I am looking at a format like 01 Jan - 31 Jan, 2020. Any suggestions on how to the get everything converted to arabic?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CultureInfo` class to convert date formats in different languages.

```
using System.Globalization;    
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd dddd , MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"));
```